# How can i make the 3 divs shown in the picture ( the images and the paragraphs) go downwards in the page

Tags: html, css

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiLz0.png)in this website that im making i want to add a slideshow in the middle of the webpage above the 3 divs shown in the image but im not sure how can i do that without adding margins and padding, i already have the display set to flex and im using a flex box but im not sure how i can just move all of them more downwards however i want

here is the html file

```
<main>
    <div class="who">
        <h1><img class ="who-we" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/who.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>Who We Are</h2>
        <p class="who-info">DSPR is an ecumenical and Church – related organization which is an integral part of the
Middle East Council of Churches (MECC).
It was founded following the 1950 Arab Israeli War and the creation of the Palestine refugee
problem.
        </p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="what">
        <h1><img class ="work" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/what.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>What We Do</h2>
        <p class="what-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat</p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>

    <div class="where">
        <h1><img class="jordan" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/where.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>Where We Work</h2>
        <p class="where-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori</p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the css file

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    color: #222;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

header{
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul li a{
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

li a:hover::before, li a:hover::after{
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}

li a::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FCAE1E;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
li a::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FCAE1E;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    height:calc(100vh - 100px);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


.who{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.what{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.where{ 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.who-we{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.work{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.jordan{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.who-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.Read-more{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.what-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.where-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The three divs (`.who`, `.what`, `.where`) will move down if you add the slideshow above them in your html. However you need to adjust a few things to achieve that. I would be inclined to remove `display: flex` from your `<main>` as a first point. Also, bear in mind that if you set the `height` of `<main>` using `vh` units there is a good chance the content will overflow the container if the user's browser is short.

The following code will give you a good starting point to get your desired layout. You can [view a codepen I've created](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/dyKqZmN) so you can see it working.

HTML

```
<main>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <!-- slideshow code -->
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="who">
            <!-- your code -->
        </div>
        <div class="what">
            <!-- your code -->
        </div>
        <div class="where">
            <!-- your code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.info { // code based on what you had in <main>
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Removing `display: flex` from `main` reverts it to using normal flow layout. You can [read more about flow layout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout). That will place your block elements one after the other from top to bottom of the page. A `<div>` is a block element so `.slideshow` will automatically be above `.info`. You can then use flex layout on `.info` to lay it out as you had intended. You can [read more about flex layout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).